# Adding New Item to SharePoint List Using REST API with Button Click

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-rest-api

I have been trying to get this function to work, adding new content to a SharePoint list with a button clicked.  The below script looks correct but when I select the button it gives me an error, 'Bad Request' and provides me with the path going to my SharePoint List I'm targeting for the test; POST https://name/name/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('views')/items ; which looks good to me.  I can't figure what is going wrong.  Can someone please see what is causing my error, because I can't. I appreciate any assistance. I replaced the actual url names, with the word "name". Thank you in advance.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery(document).on("click", '#btnClick', function(){
        CreateListItem();
  });     

   
//Retrieve list items from sharepoint using API  
function CreateListItem() {
    $.ajax
        ({
             // _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl - will give absolute URL of the site where you are running the code.
            // You can replace this with other site URL where you want to apply the function
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('views')/items",
            type: "POST",
            headers:
        {
            // Accept header: Specifies the format for response data from the server.
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            //Content-Type header: Specifies the format of the data that the client is sending to the server
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            // X-RequestDigest header: When you send a POST request, it must include the form digest value in X-RequestDigest header
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
            data: JSON.stringify
        ({
            __metadata:
            {
                // Format of the "type" is: SP.Data.<<ListName>>ListItem
                type: "SP.Data.viewsListItem"
            },
            Title: "New Title"
        }),
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
}
```

});

Comment: Hi, your code works.

Have you logged the error message?
`error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("Failed", xhr, status, error);
}`
It could tell you that you may have an incorrect metadata type.

Or how and where is this implemented? Maybe you're running into CORS issues?

You need to add a few more details.

Comment: May I also recommend this `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);` I'm not sure what your trying to achieve. I'm assuming some sort of custom form. but it might be easier to just modify the actual list forms and open them directly.